# Android-PC file transfer: cant send files over x bytes

Tags: java, android, networking, file-transfer

Im building an app to send a file like a picture from an Android phone or tablet to a computer running Java. My program *does* work, but not the way it should.

What I mean is that I want to be able to send files uncompressed from my phone to my desktop while on vacation. My phones pictures are around 7 Megabytes each. My program is able to send a file that is 22 Kilobytes as many times as I want, but anything larger than that fails. I think it may be an issue with my buffer, but I am not sure. Sending a large text file, however, leads me to believe that my large files are getting *corrupted* during transfer, since the files that appear on the PC are the right size, just not openable.

Code for Server (PC):

```
public class AEFT implements ActionListener {

    public ServerSocket server = null;
    public boolean server_up = false;
    public Socket socket = null;
    public int maxsize = 999999999;
    public String file_name = "file.txt";
    public int byteread, current;
    public JTextField fileTF;


    public void start_server() {
        String start_fail = "ERROR: Failed to start server";
        if(!server_up) {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(25000);
                server_up = true;
                System.out.println("INFO: Server started successfully.");
                wait_for_file();
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: Failed to start server.");
                System.out.println(start_fail + ": Unknown error occured.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(start_fail + ": Server already running!");
        }
    }

    public void wait_for_file() {
        try {
            socket = server.accept();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[maxsize];
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            file_name = fileTF.getText();
            String[] splitfile = file_name.split("\\.");
            File file = new File(splitfile[0] + "_" + getRandom() + "." + splitfile[1]);
            //File file = new File(file_name);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byteread = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            current = byteread;
            do {
                byteread = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length - current);
                System.out.println(byteread);
                if(byteread >= 0) current += byteread;
            } while (byteread > -1);
            out.write(buffer, 0, current);
            out.flush();
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            server.close();
        }catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        server_up = false;
        start_server();
    }
```

and the code for app (Android):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    public String IP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendB);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        IP = et.getText().toString();
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(this, OpenFileActivity.class);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_file);
        this.startActivityForResult(i, 2);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String fileName = null;
        if (resultCode == 2) {
            fileName = data.getStringExtra("fileName");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No File Selected, Cancel Or Back Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        sendTheFile ooh = new sendTheFile();
        ooh.execute(fileName,IP);
    }
}

class sendTheFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public OutputStream out = null;
    public Socket socket = null;
    public File myFile = null;
    public byte[] buffer;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        String IP = params[1];
        myFile = new File(params[0]);
        try {
            socket = new Socket(IP, 25000);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            buffer = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            out.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("TAG","Failed to send file");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

**OpenFileActivity.java**

```
public class OpenFileActivity extends Activity
    implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    ListView LvList;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    Button BtnOK;
    Button BtnCancel;

    String currentPath = null;

    public String selectedFilePath = null;
    String selectedFileName = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_file);

        try {
            LvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LvList);
            BtnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnOK);
            BtnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnCancel);
            LvList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            BtnOK.setOnClickListener(this);
            BtnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);




  setCurrentPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Error in OpenFileActivity.onCreate: " + ex.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void setCurrentPath(String path) {
        ArrayList<String> folders = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

        currentPath = path;

        File[] allEntries = new File(path).listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < allEntries.length; i++) {
            if (allEntries[i].isDirectory()) {
                folders.add(allEntries[i].getName());
            } else if (allEntries[i].isFile()) {
                files.add(allEntries[i].getName());
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(folders, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
            }
        });

        Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
            }
        });

        listItems.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++) {
            listItems.add(folders.get(i) + "/");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            listItems.add(files.get(i));
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                listItems);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        LvList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (!currentPath.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/")) {
            setCurrentPath(new File(currentPath).getParent() + "/");
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent;
        //Toast.makeText(this, v.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //switch (v.getId()) {
        //case R.id.BtnOK:

        intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("fileName", selectedFilePath);
        intent.putExtra("shortFileName", selectedFileName);
        setResult(2, intent);

        this.finish();

    }
}
```

Yes my code needs lots of improvement, that will come later.

Does anyone know how I could make it send larger files? That would be great. also I am running windows 7 java 8 64 bit. And android 7.0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you can edit your code to contain a [mcve] it would make it easier for us to help you answer your question. The more code there is, the more difficult and time-consuming it is for us to try to analyze the issue.

Comment: @DanielBickler Thank you for the reply. I edited my question to try and do "MCVE".